# C# JSON Data Array

Tags: c#, json, xml, web-services

I want to convert this style in C#.I want to add Contacts.How can I do it?

My Json:

```
[{
    "Id": "1",
    "Name": "emre",
    "Country": "istanbul"
}, {
    "Id": "2",
    "Name": "semih",
    "Country": "siirt"
}]
```

I want this style:

```
{
    "contacts": [
        {       "Id": "1",
                "Name": "emre",
                "Country": "istanbul"
        },
       {       "Id": "2",
                "Name": "semih",
                "Country": "siirt"
        }

  ]
}
```

My web service:

```
    String resultJSON = "";
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    try{
        Context.Response.Clear();
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from City", con);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt = new DataTable();
            con.Close();



        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<String, Object>> tableRows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<String, Object> row;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {                     
              row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col].ToString());
            }
            tableRows.Add(row);
        }
            resultJSON = serializer.Serialize(tableRows).ToString();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        resultJSON = ex.Message.ToString();

    }
    Context.Response.Write(resultJSON);

   // return resultJSON;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly serializing the rows create a data model say class named Contact which has the different properties like Id , Name, country , fill it up from the database  and use a library like [JSON.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize it .

Something similar should work for your datamodel. Please look the [Serializing Collections](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm)  from JSON.net

```
Product p1 = new Product
 {
  Name = "Product 1",
  Price = 99.95m,
  ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2000, 12, 29, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
 };
Product p2 = new Product
{
 Name = "Product 2",
 Price = 12.50m,
 ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2009, 7, 31, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
};
ProductList productList = new ProductList ();
p.Add(p1);
p.Add(p2);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(productList , Formatting.Indented);

class ProductList 
{
  Public List<Product> products{get;set;}
   // Add method or other methods you require for your collection

}
```

Comment: @EmreAslan pls look the edited answer. Something similar would help

Comment: @EmreAslan pls mark it as answer if it has answered your question

Answer (score 0):

Like Ashley John said, it would be smart to create a class representing the data json data structure. If you are lazy, or i doubt how it should look, you can use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to create the class.

Then use a json serializer of your choice, f.x. JSON.net as mentioned by Ashley J, to serialize the entire enumerable of Contacts at once. If you need the json value to be named 'contacts', you can create a containing class with field for the enumerable of contacts, so that when you serialize the containing class, you get the wanted result